# error ID returned 1 exit status, can't find my mistake

Tags: c

So i am writing a program that prints a list of levels in a game, along with a count of how many players are at each level. The level will be determined by the amount of health points are entered. I'm screwing up my do-while loop somewhere because it should read all input until the number -1 in inputted, exiting the loop. I can't find the error so if someone could point it out I would appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    void updateLevel(int, int []);
    void displayLevels(int []);

    int point, c; 
    int Level [6];

    for (c = 0; c < 6; c++)
        Level [c] = 0;

    do {
        printf("\n Enter Player Points: ");
        scanf("%d", &point);
        {
            if(point == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            updateLevel(point, Level);
        }
    } while (1);
    displayLevels(Level);

    return (0);
}

void updateLevel(int p, int lev[])
{
    if (p >= 0 && p <= 9) {
        lev[0]++;
    } else if (p >= 10 && p <= 19) {
        lev[1]++;
    } else if (p >= 20 && p <= 29) {
        lev[2]++;
    } else if (p >= 30 && p <= 39) {
        lev[3]++;
    } else if (p >= 40 && p <= 49) {
        lev[4]++;
    } else {
        lev[5]++;
    }
}

void displayLevel(int L[])
{
    int c;

    for (c = 0; c < 6; c++)
    {
        printf("\n Level = %d \t Counter = %d", c+1, L[c]);
    }
}
```

Comment: do ... while(1); won't stop. do ... while(point != -1); is probably what you want.

Comment: What is your input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: The code as posted doesn't compile:  `void displayLevel(int L[])` --> `void displayLevels(int L[])`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't even compile. I'm assuming that's your question? You declare and use `displayLevels`, but the function is defined as `displayLevel`. Then it compiles and works as you say (takes input until -1, then prints 'levels' output, whatever that is.)

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's important to cut and paste both code and error messages instead of retyping them.

In the title, it says:

```
ID returned 1 exit status
```

However, if you compile this code you get this:

```
ld returned 1 exit status
```

The first letter is `l` (ell), not `I` (i).  `ld` is the linker, which tells us there is a linker error.

If you included the output line immediately before this one:

```
undefined reference to `displayLevels'
```

The error is apparent.  There is no function named `displayLevels`.  There is one however named `displayLevel`.  So you have a typo in your function name.

Comment: I will do so from now on, thank you for your input. Damn typo!